# What is wrong with this code? Huffman encoding

Tags: java, algorithm, dictionary, huffman-code

In this bit of code, i am attempting to split a string into Characters and place each character into a map. If the same Character appears more than once I put a counter on it and place it back into the map, incrementing the integer(frequency).

```
public class FrequencyMap {
   public static Map<Character, Integer> generateMap(String s){
       HashMap<Character, Integer> myMap = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
       //generate a map of frequencies of the characters in s
       //need to break the string down into individual characters, sort them
       //in there frequencies then place them in map
       for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++){
           //break string into characters
           //need to determine how many characters make up the string, can do this by 
           //putting a counter on each letter that appears when the string is being 
           //broken down, if a letter reoccurs increment the counter by one.
           s.substring(i);
           char ch = s.charAt(i);
           myMap.put(ch, i);
           //calculating the occurence of a character in a string.
           if(myMap.containsKey(ch)){                   
               myMap.put(ch, myMap.get(i) + 1);                   
                  }//end of if statement
           }//end of for loop          
           return myMap;
       }//end of public generateMap()
   }//end of FrequencyMap
```

Here is the main

```
   public static void main(String args[]){

       String str = "missisippi";

       Map frequencyMap = FrequencyMap.generateMap(str);
       HuffmanTree tree = new HuffmanTree(frequencyMap);
       Map<Character, String> encodingMap = tree.getEncodingMap();

       String encoded = tree.encode(str, encodingMap);
       System.out.println(encoded);     
   }//end of main
```

Comment: What is the problem you're experiencing with your code?

Comment: The line `s.substring(i);` is a no-op. You take a substring of `s` and then discard it.

Comment: with just a quick glance. `s.substring(i);` is not changing `s`.

Comment: After `char ch = s.charAt(i); myMap.put(ch, i);`, `myMap` will always contain a mapping for `ch`. You should not insert anything before you look inside.

Comment: Null Pointer at huffmantree.FrequencyMap.generateMap(FrequencyMap.java:29)
 at huffmantree.HuffmanTree.main(HuffmanTree.java:129)
Java Result: 1

Comment: Dave, perhaps you should go back and accept some answers to your older questions. People might be less likely to provide help if they don't think you'll look at the answers anyway.

Comment: Ad `myMap.get(i)`: I'm sure you want `myMap.get(ch)`.

Comment: The whole line `s.substring();` can be removed, it doesn't make sense in thsi algorithm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay a few things...

Strings are immutable!!

```
s.substring(i);
```

should really be

```
s = s.substring(i);
```

Although I'm still not quite sure what the point of this is altogether.

---

Secondly..

These lines don't make sense

```
myMap.put(ch, i);

if(myMap.containsKey(ch)){                   
    myMap.put(ch, myMap.get(i) + 1);                   
}
```

You just added the key `ch` and then you immediately ask if the map contains `ch` - that will always be true.

I think you might have meant to put the `if`-statement *first* and to put `myMap.put(ch, 1)` in an `else`-clause. Oh, and `myMap.get(i)` probably should have been `myMap.get(ch)`.

Answer (score 0):

You are initialising your counters with the character position:

```
myMap.put(ch, i);
```

where you want:

```
myMap.put(ch, 1);
```

You also want to check the map for an already existing character *before* you initialise the counter, incrementing the counter of it does (using `get(ch)` not `get(i)`), giving:

```
    char ch = s.charAt(i);
    //calculating the occurence of a character in a string.
    if (myMap.containsKey(ch)){                   
        myMap.put(ch, myMap.get(ch) + 1);
    } else {
        myMap.put(ch, 1);
    }//end of if statement
```